# Using Multiple "Layered" SQL Server queries with parameters in Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have tried to find answers to this question on the net but am not really getting anywhere.

I tried to do screen shots but don't have enough rep. Anyway.
Here is my current query structure.

### Tables:

- tblInventoryItems(intSerial, intItem, intStyle) -This is the list of current items that are on inventory(built or unbuilt)
- tblLocations(intLocationID, chrLocationName, intLotType)
- tblItemStyles(intItemStyleID, intBasic Style)
- tblItemList(intItemID, intType, intSubtype, intStyle)
- tblCommissions(intBuildEvent, intItemType, intItemSubtype)
- tblBuildEvents(intSerial, intBuildEventType, dtEventDate)

## First Set of Queries

### qryCompletedBarns:

```
SELECT dbo.tblInventoryItems.intSerial,dbo.tblBuildEvents.dtEventDate
FROM dbo.tblItemList 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblItemStyles ON 
           dbo.tblItemList.intStyle = dbo.tblItemStyles.intBasicStyle 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblInventoryItems ON 
           dbo.tblItemList.intItemID = dbo.tblInventoryItems.intItem AND
          dbo.tblItemStyles.intItemStyleID = dbo.tblInventoryItems.intStyle
INNER JOIN dbo.tblCommissions ON 
           dbo.tblItemList.intSubType = dbo.tblCommissions.intItemSubtype
AND dbo.tblItemList.intType = dbo.tblCommissions.intItemType 

INNER JOIN dbo.tblBuildEvents ON 
dbo.tblBuildEvents.intBuildEventType = dbo.tblCommissions.intBuildEvent AND
dbo.tblInventoryItems.intSerial = dbo.tblBuildEvents.intSerial
WHERE        (dbo.tblCommissions.ynCompletesBarn = 1)
```

So First we select all items that have a build event that qualifies them as completed. An item can have multiple build events but there is only one that qualifies it as completed

### qryCompletedBarnDateFilter:

```
SELECT qryCompletedBarns.intSerial, qryCompletedBarns.dtEventDate
FROM qryCompletedBarns
WHERE (((qryCompletedBarns.dtEventDate)<=InventoryDate()));
```

Then we jump to Access and filter those results by a UDF that pulls the criteria for the build date of the item(Saved report definitions are stored in a table).

Now, we have a list of all Inventory items that meet the first criteria, which is that they must be built on or before the Inventory Date that the user selects.

## Second set of queries:

### qryInventoryLogDateFilter:

```
SELECT tblHaulLogs.*, tblHaulLogs.dtmHaulDate
FROM tblHaulLogs
WHERE (((tblHaulLogs.dtmHaulDate)<=InventoryDate()));
```

Get all the Haullogs (or you could call them inventory transactions) that are equal to or older than the InventoryDate criteria.

### qryLastLogForBarn:

```
SELECT t1.intSerial, t1.intHaulType, t1.intDestinationSource, t1.intDestination
FROM qryInventoryLogDateFilter AS t1 
LEFT JOIN qryInventoryLogDateFilter AS t2 
ON (t1.intLogID < t2.intLogID) AND (t1.intSerial = t2.intSerial)
WHERE t2.intLogID IS NULL;
```

Get the last inventory transaction for each Inventory Item. This query is actually very fast when executed on the server natively.

### qryInventoryCurrentCustomer:

```
SELECT tblSales.intSerial, tblCustomers.chrFirstName + ' ' + tblCustomers.chrLastName 
AS chrCustomerName, tblSales.dtSaleDate
FROM tblSales INNER JOIN tblCustomers ON 
tblSales.intCustomer = tblCustomers.intCustID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblHaulLogs ON
tblSales.intSaleID = tblHaulLogs.intOrigon
WHERE (tblHaulLogs.intHaulType IS NULL) AND (tblSales.bolSaleCancelled = 0)
      OR (tblHaulLogs.intHaulType <> 3) AND
         (tblSales.intOrderType <4) AND (tblSales.bolSaleCancelled = 0)
GROUP BY tblSales.intSerial, tblCustomers.chrFirstName + ' ' + tblCustomers.chrLastName, 
tblSales.dtSaleDate, tblSales.intOrderType;
```

This query does not actually return an "Inventory Item" but rather checks the sales table and returns a customer name if the inventory item was sold.

Now we finally join the two "sections" and the "Current Customer Query":

```
SELECT qryCompletedBarnDateFilter.intSerial, qryLastLogForBarn.intHaulType,
       IIf(IsNull([intDestination]),7,[intDestination]) AS Location,
qryInventoryCurrentCustomer.chrCustomerName,
qryInventoryCurrentCustomer.dtSaleDate, qryCompletedBarnDateFilter.dtEventDate
FROM (qryCompletedBarnDateFilter
LEFT JOIN qryLastLogForBarn
     ON qryCompletedBarnDateFilter.intSerial = qryLastLogForBarn.intSerial) 
LEFT JOIN qryInventoryCurrentCustomer
     ON qryCompletedBarnDateFilter.intSerial = qryInventoryCurrentCustomer.intSerial
WHERE (((qryLastLogForBarn.intDestinationSource)=1 
Or (qryLastLogForBarn.intDestinationSource) Is Null));
```

Then we join to the "Locations" table to get the name of the inventory item's location,  and also filter out a certain type of location.

qryRetailBarnsOnInventory:

```
SELECT qryBarnsOnInventory.intSerial, qryBarnsOnInventory.Location,
tblLocations.chrLocationName, qryBarnsOnInventory.chrCustomerName, 
qryBarnsOnInventory.dtEventDate, qryBarnsOnInventory.intHaulType
FROM tblLocations 
INNER JOIN qryBarnsOnInventory 
ON tblLocations.intLocationID = qryBarnsOnInventory.Location
WHERE (((tblLocations.intLotType)=1));
```

### The Final Query:

```
SELECT tblItemStyles.chrItemStyle, tblInventoryItems.intSerial,
        tblItemSizeList.intItemSize, tblItemPrices.ccyPrice, 
       tblInventoryItems.txtOptions, qryRetailBarnsOnInventory.chrCustomerName, 
       qryRetailBarnsOnInventory.dtEventDate, qryRetailBarnsOnInventory.intHaulType, 
       qryRetailBarnsOnInventory.chrLocationName, tblItemList.intType, 
       tblItemList.intSubType, tblItemList.intStyle, tblItemSizes.intItemSizeID, 
       tblItemStyles.intItemStyleID, tblItemPrices.intPriceSheet, 
       tblInventoryItems.bolinTransit
FROM tblItemSizeList INNER JOIN (tblItemSizes INNER JOIN 
      (qryRetailBarnsOnInventory INNER JOIN (((tblItemList INNER JOIN 
      tblItemPrices ON tblItemList.intItemID = tblItemPrices.intItemID) 
    INNER JOIN tblItemStyles ON tblItemList.intStyle = tblItemStyles.intBasicStyle) 
    INNER JOIN tblInventoryItems 
    ON (tblItemList.intItemID = tblInventoryItems.intItem) 
    AND (tblItemStyles.intItemStyleID = tblInventoryItems.intStyle)) 
    ON qryRetailBarnsOnInventory.intSerial = tblInventoryItems.intSerial) 
    ON tblItemSizes.intItemSizeID = tblItemList.intSize) 
    ON tblItemSizeList.intItemSizeID = tblItemSizes.intSize
WHERE (((tblItemList.intType) Like ItemType()) 
    AND ((tblItemList.intSubType) Like ItemSubType()) 
    AND ((tblItemList.intStyle) Like BasicStyle()) 
    AND ((tblItemSizes.intItemSizeID) Like ItemSize()) 
    AND ((tblItemStyles.intItemStyleID) Like SubStyle()) 
    AND ((tblItemPrices.intPriceSheet)=1) 
    AND ((tblInventoryItems.bolinTransit)=False) 
    AND ((IIf(IsNull([intHaulType]),2,3)) Like NewUsed()) 
    AND ((IIf(IsNull([chrCustomerName]),2,3)) Like IsSold()) 
    AND ((qryRetailBarnsOnInventory.Location) Like LotID()));
```

### Summary:

In plain English, here is what I want to happen:
Get all Inventory Items from the inventory items table that were completed on or before the date criteria, then get the last inventory transaction on or before the date criteria for each of those items. And then filter by additional criteria that the user provides

I have the correct results but it is SLOW! Like 10-15 seconds. And we do a tremendous amount of queries every day.

What my idea was is to put this all on SQL Server in sprocs or views. If I do this all with views on SQL server and type manual criteria in, it's blazing fast. The problem I have is that every query requires a parameter. Not just the last one. I can pass parameters for the last query all right with a passthrough query but how do I pass the date criteria parameters for the first query?

### EDIT:

Would it be possible to get the date criteria from another table? The criteria is stored in another table in the DB. If I could perform some kind of lookup to get that value and use it as the criteria that would make life really simple.

Comment: Are you looking for the VBA to create queries? What do you need?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: sorry I'm not done with the question. accidentally hit the submit button before I was done

Comment: you seem to have the option to use MS SQL Server.  To me that's the best option.  You seem to have already tried this and proven the speed.  The question seems to be:  how do you pass all the parameters into the stored procedure in SQL server.  Can you post what you have written in SQL Server?  And is the data originally from a SQL Server Database?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go out of town for a week.

Comment: The queries that I posted are exactly what I have in sql server except for some slight formatting. The real hurdle I am having is with the qryCompletedBarnDateFilter query. The InventoryDate function in there is the function that in Access uses to get the date to filter by and I'm not sure how to reproduce that function in SQL Server. All the function does is looks up the date criteria in a table and returns that. And yes all data is in sql server

Comment: Well I guess nobody knows the answer to this? Is there another site with better SQL expertise I should ask on? If anybody needs clarification please say so. This is a very real problem for me.